# bug while inserting at the tail of LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

Trying to insert at the end of a singly linked list, however I find some error in output. This is my code :

```
    public class LinkRemove
{
    private static final int N = 5;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sx = new Scanner(System.in);
        Node first = new Node();
        Node tail = new Node();
        first=tail;

        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            Node current = new Node();

            if(tail==null)
            {
                tail.data = sx.nextInt();
            }

            else
            {
                current.data = sx.nextInt();
                while(tail.link!=null)
                    tail = tail.link;
                tail.link = current;
            }


        }

        for(Node d = first;d.link!=null;d=d.link)
            System.out.println(d.data);


    }

    private static class Node
    {
        int  data;
        Node link;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is , when I give input :

`2 4 6 8 10`

I am getting output as :

`0 2 4 6 8`

What might be possible causing this? And why do I get a `0` in the beginning?
Please give a descriptive answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    Scanner sx = new Scanner(System.in);
    Node first = null;
    Node tail = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        Node current = new Node();
        current.data = sx.nextInt();

        if (tail == null)
        {
            first = tail = current;
        }
        else
        {
            tail = tail.link = current;
        }
    }
    for(Node d = first; d != null; d = d.link)
        System.out.println(d.data);
```

Comment: Can you please explain what this line `first = tail.link = current;` do ?

Comment: It is equivalent to ```tail.link = current; first = current;```.  Assignment operator ```=``` is right associative.

Answer (score 0):

The first 0 comes from the default value of the field in a node (`Node tail = new Node();`). You actually want to set that to `null` instead of `new Node()`. The same goes to `first`. In fact, why don't you just write:

```
Node tail = null;
Node first = tail;
```

Like what Mike said, your terminating condition is incorrect.

Also,

```
if(tail==null)
{
   tail.data = sx.nextInt();
}
```

doesn't make sense at all. If the code reaches `tail.data = ...`, it will be a NullPointerException. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a little bit

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sx = new Scanner(System.in);
    Node first = null;
    Node tail = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        Node current = new Node();
        current.data = sx.nextInt();

        if(first == null) {
            first = current;
            tail = first;
        } else {
            tail.link = current;
            tail = current;
        }
    }

    for (Node d = first; d != null; d = d.link)
        System.out.println(d.data);

}
```

The logic you have used to set the data in nodes is incorrect. First you have to set the first Node and set tail = first.
Then, add new Nodes to tail: tail.link = current.

Hope this helps.